# Using theorem environment but theorems not displayed properly

Tags: environments, theorems

I am using a class file `aptpub.cls` (Applied Probability, it can be found [here](http://www.appliedprobability.org/data/files/Submittal%20Guidelines/aptpub.cls)) and one of the suggestions for an environment for theorems in that class file is `\newtheorem{theorem}{\noindent Theorem}`. I am also using `amsmath` package. So if I use the aforementioned environment for a theorem and if the code for the theorem is

```
\documentclass{aptpub}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\noindent Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    \label{t1}
    abc=xyz
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

then it is printed in pdf file as:
[image]

May I know how it can be corrected? Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing. Furthermore, since `aptpub.cls` is no standard class you might want to add a link to it.

Comment: @campa, I have edited the question now. Thanks.

Comment: @egreg Added the code now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class is incompatible with `amsthm` because it uses the (obsolete) package `theorem` and already defines a `theorem` environment.

So just do

```
\documentclass{aptpub}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{t1}
    abc=xyz
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

and you'll be on the right track.